# How to draw color line with size in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science, geospatial, geom-curve

I have a data with over 700 observations but below is a sample. Using geom_curve I want to make a plot where the line size(total_trips) corresponds to a color say 3 different colors.  For instance between 0-100 (total_trips) can have a color of red

```
df <- data.frame(
 origin_x = c(659627.8,642136.2,648774.7,659627.8,659627.8,658455.7,659627.8,659620.6,661641.8,656246.4),
 origin_y = c(6473200,6473200,6462166,6473200,6473200,6467413,6473200,6467163,6479577,6487039),
 dest_x = c(642136.2,659627.8,659627.8,648774.7,659620.6,659627.8,658455.7,659627.8,659627.8,659627.8),
 dest_y = c(6456563,6473200,6473200,6462166,6467163,6473200,6467413,6473200,6473200,6473200
),
 total_trips = c(4002,49878,2011,500,100,3000,2500,654,900,600))
```

I tried

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=shapefile, colour='grey', fill='grey93', size = 0.25) + 
    geom_curve(
        data = df), 
        aes(
            x = origin_x,
            xend = dest_x,
            y = origin_y,
            yend = dest_y,
             size = n,
            colour= as.factor(c('red','blue'))),
        curvature = 0.3
    )  + scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.09,1)) +
    theme(
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 6),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 1),
        plot.caption.position = 'plot',
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(color = NA, size = 0.5, fill=NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black', fill = NA, size=0.2) ,
        legend.position = c(0.89,0.15),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.4, 'cm'), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=7)  
    ) +
    annotation_scale(location = 'br', style = 'ticks') + coord_sf(crs=3301) +
    annotation_north_arrow(location = 'tr', width = unit(0.20, 'cm'),height = unit(0.5,'cm'))
```

Comment: Could you please provide more data, we can't reproduce now your problem.

Comment: Please provide a desired output, it's quite unclear to me what you want to achieve

Comment: @Quinten I added some more data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly - you want to change the colour of the line according to a categorised continuous variable (`total_trips`), we can do this:

1. Use `cut` to categorise the variable and give labels to the groups
2. Add this new variable to the `aes(colour =`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- df |> mutate(trips = cut(total_trips, c(0, 2000, 5000, 50000),
                               labels = c("0-2k", "2k-5k", "5k-50k")))

ggplot() +
  geom_curve(data = df, aes(x = origin_x,
                            xend = dest_x,
                            y = origin_y,
                            yend = dest_y,
                            size = total_trips,
                            colour = trips
                            ))
```

Output:
[image: Graph]

Not sure if this is what you want, though – your sample dataset doesn't contain the variable `n` that you mention in `size = n`, and you haven't provided us with `shapefile`.

Comment: quite the idea only that the color should correspond with the total_trips. Here the color of total_trips is black but I want it to correspond with the colors on the plot. So for instance all trips that fall within the group of 10000 should have a color of green.

Comment: The colours are right – do you also want the line thickness to follow the same 3 groups as the colours? I’m a bit confused because on one hand you seem to want groups and on the other one you want to use total_trips which is a continuous variable.

Comment: Yes exactly the line thickness should also follow the same 3 groups of colors

Comment: Just change `size = total_trips` to `size = trips` in my code then